# How to handle IE9 when using Angular 2 pushstate?

Tags: angular, cross-browser, internet-explorer-9, url-routing

When using Angular 2, it seems like the default routing settings will use pushstate when it is available, and fallback to hash style routing otherwise, most notably on IE9.

But due to this, if a user copies a URL from IE9 and shares it with someone who uses Chrome, the link will not work, and vice versa for Chrome URL to IE9.

What is the standard Angular 2 way to handle this problem?

Comment: I would really like to drop IE9 but unfortunately in this case that's not an option. Plus, Angular 2 claims to support IE9, so I would expect that there is some kind of easy solution.

Comment: There is no solution to your problem. Maybe that you can fix it inside your webserver, to add a hash if its IE9 and remove it its not

Comment: So if I don't have access to webserver, there is not another way to solve the problem using Angular 2/Javascript?

Comment: No, if you want to support IE9, you should set the `{hash: true}` in your router configuration. This way the URLs will be the same on chrome and ie9